# Add filter to blogroll widget

Tags: widgets, filters

I'm trying to add `<i class="icon-ok"></i>` before the content inside the `<li>` of the blogroll widget. I'm assuming that's done through the link_title filter, but I can't find a suitable explanation as to how.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just wondering any particular reason you're using `<i>` and not `<em>`? It won't make a difference in the answer though.

Comment: I think it's because i is a presentation element while em is meant to denote emphasis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter the arguments for the blogroll:

```
add_filter( 'widget_links_args', 'wpse_76521_filter_blogroll' );

function wpse_76521_filter_blogroll( $args )
{
    $li_start = isset ( $args['before'] ) ? $args['before'] : '<li>';
    $args['before'] = $li_start . '<i class="icon-ok"></i>';
    return $args;
}
```

#### Explanation

1. The blogroll is created by the widget class `WP_Widget_Links`.
2. This class calls `wp_list_bookmarks()` with some prepared widget arguments which we can filter with `widget_links_args`.
3. `wp_list_bookmarks()` calls `_walk_bookmarks()` and passes the original arguments through.
4. `_walk_bookmarks()` accepts an argument `'before'` that defaults to `<li>`.
5. So we add that argument to `widget_links_args` in (2.) and let it fall through until it arrives in `_walk_bookmarks()` (4.).

#### Alternative

You could use CSS instead:

```
.widget_links li
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    background:   url(path/to/icon.png) 0% 50% no-repeat transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Completely missed the widget_links_args.